# How the out put become 1 in the following code can any one explain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How the out put become 1 in the following code can any one explain?

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
   foo = 10;
   return;
   function foo() {}
}
bar();
alert(foo);
```

Comment: you are defined a function with name `foo`..... so `foo=10` updating that... not the variable in the global context... just an assumption ;)

Comment: Why are you even writing code like this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a function with the same name `foo` so inside the method `foo`(act as a local variable) referring to function. You can see the `console.log(foo)` as the function inside `bar()` method.

```js
var foo = 1;

function bar() {
  console.log(foo);
  foo = 10;
  return;

  function foo() {}
}
var b=bar();
alert(foo);
```

---

What you can do is get the variable in global context(`window['foo']`) and update or rename the variable or function.

```js
var foo = 1;

function bar() {
  window['foo'] = 10;
  return;

  function foo() {}
}
var b=bar();
alert(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Var hoisting** is a technique used in java script according to Mozilla Developer Network  [as mention here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

which says..

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This behavior is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

so when you declare `function foo() {}`
 inside `function bar() {...}` it is treated as local variable and hence its value gets destroyed outside of bar().

below is the code which produces same behaviour:

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    foo = 10;
    return;
    var foo;
}
bar();
alert(foo);
```

your code just declares the variable foo as a method.

Answer (score 0):

See the console.log:

```js
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    console.log(foo)//function foo() {}
   foo = 10;
    console.log(foo)//10
   return;
   function foo() {}
}
bar();
alert(foo);
```

Function declarations and function variables are always moved (‘hoisted’) to the top of their JavaScript scope by the JavaScript interpreter.

So it runs more like this:

```js
var foo = 1;

function bar() {
  function foo() {}
  console.log(foo);
  foo = 10;
  return;
  //function foo() {}
}
var b=bar();
alert(foo);
```

So the foo in bar is a local variable, and overrided by 10. And the global foo is not be affected.
So the foo is 1.

You can refer to this [enter link description here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)